# How to write REST High level Client Query for prefix Suggestion?

Tags: elasticsearch

The below query work fine on kibana. I want to write the same for ReastHighLevel Client.

```
 POST taxon/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "name-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "man", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "name" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write above query using RestHighLevelClient.
The one i came up with doesnot help

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("taxon"); 
        searchRequest.types("taxon");
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        SuggestionBuilder termSuggestionBuilder =SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion("name").text(data); 

        SuggestBuilder suggestBuilder = new SuggestBuilder();

        suggestBuilder.addSuggestion("name-suggest", termSuggestionBuilder); 

        searchSourceBuilder.suggest(suggestBuilder);

    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse=null;
        try {
            searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("excetion is here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(searchResponse);
```

The above query gives the correct result, but how to get the _source entry out of it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source comes from the options in the suggest field. So I used this code after your code. It gives all the possible values in the suggest field.

/// * same as previous lines

```
SearchResponse searchResponse=null;
        try {
            searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("exception is here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(searchResponse);


        Suggest suggest = searchResponse.getSuggest(); 
        System.out.println("suggest variable has:  "+suggest);

        List<String> returnList =new ArrayList<>();


        CompletionSuggestion termSuggestion = suggest.getSuggestion("name-suggest");
        List<CompletionSuggestion.Entry.Option> termSuggestion1 = termSuggestion.getOptions();
        System.out.println("term suggestion value is:  "+termSuggestion1);

        for (CompletionSuggestion.Entry.Option entry : termSuggestion1) { 

            System.out.println("termsuggestion.entry value:  "+entry.getText());


            String suggestText = entry.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("suggest text value: "+suggestText);
            returnList.add(suggestText);
            System.out.println("output of return:  "+returnList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fetch all the suggestion responses of the completion suggester like below in java

```
/* Create a Consumer to process each of the suggestion */

    Consumer<Suggestion<? extends org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest.Suggestion.Entry<? extends Option>>> suggestionConsumer = suggestion -> {

                for(org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest.Suggestion.Entry<? extends Option> entry: suggestion.getEntries()){
                     for(Option option:  entry.getOptions()){
                       //PRINT EACH SUGGESTION TEXT VALUE
                         System.out.println(option.getText());
                     }
                }

            };
      /* Fetch search results */
     searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest); 
    /* Fetch search response suggestions */
    Suggest suggestions=searchResponse.getSuggest();
   /* Handle each of the suggestions with foreach */
    suggestions.forEach(suggestionConsumer);


Please note that JAVA imports I have used are
Suggestion: org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest.Suggestion
Entry:      org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest.Suggestion.Entry
Option:     org.elasticsearch.search.suggest.Suggest.Suggestion.Entry.Option;
```